How to update hyperlink cell number automatically
I am working on google sheet and I am a new bee, I need some help to get to the last empty row in a current sheet, I have some hundreds of rows when I open sheet I need to scroll all the way down to the last empty cell in a row the short way is, I have set the hyperlink with a range cell number when I click on Sheet1!A16 this takes me to get to the last empty cell, So what I am looking is to update this(Sheet1!A16) cell number automatically upto last empty cell so that when I open next time cell gets automatically updated with last empty cell number.
Can we update that?here the example below to get an idea. Any help appreciate it.
.

I made a Named Function and called it GETLASTROW.
Formula Definition
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX((range<>"")*(ROW(range))))

Function Description
Return the last active row in a specified sheet, gaps in data are accounted for
Use as follows
=GETLASTROW(A1:A)


I created a library of named functions, feel free to make a copy and you can import into your projects named functions as needed
Named Functions
